# Opentok | Get online users

Tags: opentok

This is my code for opentok connect. How to know when other user connected or disconnected to the session ? So i can populate my online friends list like social network site.  Then i can initiate a chat with them.

```
function connect() {
        OT.on("exception", exceptionHandler);

        // Un-comment the following to set automatic logging:
        OT.setLogLevel(OT.DEBUG);

        if (!(OT.checkSystemRequirements())) {
            alert("You don't have the minimum requirements to run this application.");
        } else {
            session = OT.initSession(sessionId);    // Initialize session
            session.connect(apiKey, token);

            // Add event listeners to the session

            session.on('sessionConnected', sessionConnectedHandler);
            session.on('sessionDisconnected', sessionDisconnectedHandler);
            session.on('connectionCreated', connectionCreatedHandler);
            session.on('connectionDestroyed', connectionDestroyedHandler);
            session.on('streamCreated', streamCreatedHandler);
            session.on('streamDestroyed', streamDestroyedHandler);
            session.on("signal", signalEventHandler);

        }

    }

function sessionConnectedHandler(event) {
    // i am connected .... do something after connected
    document.getElementById("User_name").innerHTML = user_name;
    document.getElementById("disconnectLink").style.display  = 'block';


    //startPublishing();

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function `connectionCreatedHandler` will get called each time another user connects, and `connectionDestroyedHandler` will get called each time a user disconnects.

For a sample app that has a "Buddy List" like functionality, see [Presence Kit](https://github.com/opentok/presencekit-php). Demo: http://presencekit-php.herokuapp.com/

Comment: I saw you app. How to text chat with one to one user when they are in video call  ?

Comment: @Ankur Presence kit not found